# Animate spatial points/vectors with tmap

Tags: r, geospatial, tmap

I'd like to visualize the transition of species occurrence across time as a gif file, while showing the changes in sea surface temperature in the same time frame. Simply put, I'd like to produce an animation that shows the temporal changes in temperature along with occurrence data.

I've managed to animate the temperature (a list of raster layers downloaded from nasa) using `tmap`, but I couldn't do it for the species data (converted to SpatialPointDataFrame). I thought if I could stack the shapefiles, like stacking rasters to produce rasterStack, it'd work. But I failed. Can anyone help? Here's a snippet of my code:

```
shapes <- list.files(".", pattern = 'shp')
sh <- lapply(shapes, read_sf)

library(tmap)
anim <- tm_shape(raster.files) + tm_raster(palette = "viridis") + 
  tm_shape(sh) + tm_dots(col="red") +
  tm_facets(nrow = 1, ncol = 1) 

tmap_animation(anim, "sst.gif")
```

[image]